# Python "constant" redeclare in every periodic run

Tags: python

Is there any problem, if in a periodic script I have a "constant" variable and I redeclare it in every run?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
PATH_PATTERN = '/home/%s/config.xml'
PATH = None

def periodic_execution(function):
    PATH = PATH_PATTERN % get_user()

    interval_in_sec = 1000
    threading.Timer(interval_in_sec,periodic_execution,[function]).start()
    function()
    # in function i use the PATH variable

def main():

    periodic_execution(tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I know that constant not will be constant...

Comment: Then it wouldn't be constant any more...

Comment: Please give a small code example showing what you mean.

Comment: You don't really declare variables in Python.

Comment: Hi @tmsblgh, this kind of question probably is off-topic here, since your code works and the question itself is primarily opinion-based. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PauloScardine: code does not work because he forgot  to declare the variable `global`. And I do not think that codereview fellows like primarily opinion based questions...

Comment: Global mutable variables are bad juju, why don't you just pass `path` as an argument to `function`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Beware**! In shown code, the `PATH` variable is a global one, but in `periodic_execution` you assign to `PATH` before using it and without declaring it as `global` => Python actually creates a local PATH variable in the function and leaves the global untouched which is certainly not what you expect.

You should write:

```
def periodic_execution(function):
    global PATH
    PATH = PATH_PATTERN % get_user()
```

to change a global variable.

But this is by no way a *constant*. AFAIK you cannot declare true constants in Python, even if you can build read only properties.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also look at the keyword **global** in Python? See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them). It is necessary since you change the variable in a function.

Comment: This is terrible as an answer - it is OK if you post it as a comment.